# Access port which is bind to 127.0.0.1 inside a docker container

Tags: networking, docker

Suppose you have a node server like this

```
import http from 'http';

server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
    response.end(`It works`);
});

server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1', () => {
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

Now, I would like to run this in a docker container, and expose the port, such that I can type `http://localhost:8080` inside my browser. Normally this wouldn't be a problem, **but** this time port `8080` is bind to `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0`

Inside the docker file I `EXPOSE 8080`. Now, I've tried different things to accomplish this

```
$> docker run -itd --network=host --name server node_server
$> docker run -itd -P --network=host --name server node_server
$> docker run -itd -p 8080:8080 --network=host --name server node_server
```

I did the same for `bridge`, but none of the above worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's not going to work, I don't think. 127.0.0.1 is assigned to the loopback interface, which is not connected to anything.

Comment: Can you modify the docker image to also contain something which can proxy the requests like [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/) or [caddy](https://github.com/mholt/caddy)?

Comment: In my case I need to use third party software which binds its ports on the loopback interface. I think it would be really nice if you can share the hosts loopback interface with a container.